# Fluid filled harmonic oscillator

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acceleration, harmonic-oscillator, harmonics

A vessel (preferably circular) filled with water is accelerating unidirectionally such that the level of water is higher on one end than the other. What I want to know is that if the vessel is immediately stopped, the water level will force itself back to the equilibrium point, but in doing so push the other end up. If water is an ideal fluid, what type of oscillation will occur in this situation.

I can tell that maybe the mathematical expression for this oscillation will be complex, but please do let me know if I am thinking this correctly.

I am considering, finding the oscillation equation for infinitesimally small u-tubes(considering a 2-d plane) and integrating it to get the final expression.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following diagram:

[image: U tube with fluid.]

A U tube contains a fluid with higher level in the right hand side. This could be achieved as you suggested or more simply by applying a partial vacuum on the right hand side: the higher (atmospheric) pressure in the left tube then pushes the fluid up into the right side, until a level difference of $y$ is achieved.

At $t=0$ we break the vacuum. It can now be shown that the system has potential energy $U$:

$$U=mg\frac{y}{2},$$

where $m$ is the mass of the fluid column of height $y$:

$$m=\rho Ay,$$

with $\rho$ the density of the fluid and $A$ the cross-section of the tube.

So that:

$$U=\frac{\rho Agy^2}{2}.$$

Ignoring for now all viscous friction the fluid might experience during flow (we're assuming a perfectly smooth pipe) potential energy will now be converted to kinetic energy.

Kinetic energy of a column of fluid of mass $M$ (that is the total mass of the fluid in the U tube) is given by:

$$K=\frac{Mv^2}{2},$$

where $v$ is the velocity of the fluid column and $v=\frac{dy}{dt}$.

Assuming no energy losses then at all times the total energy of the system is:

$$T=U+K$$

Now let us set up a Newtonian equation of motion. The weight of the column of height $y$ exerts a force on the whole column of:

$$\rho Agy$$

So that the equation of motion becomes:

$$Ma+\rho Agy=0,$$

where $a$ is the acceleration the column of fluid experiences and $a=\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$, so:

$$M\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+\rho Agy=0$$

This is a the equation of motion of a simple Harmonic Oscillator and assuming at $t=0$, $v=0$ and $y=y_0$ then the solution is:

$$\large{y=y_0\cos\omega t}$$

where $\omega$ is the angular speed, $\omega=\frac{2\pi}{T}$ with $T$ the period of oscillation.

It can further be shown that:

$$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{\rho Ag}{M}}.$$

In reality, due to inevitable friction, $T=U+K$ will not be respected fully and the oscillation will be a damped harmonic oscillation.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how to apply this knowledge to a continuous volume,consisting of u-tubes of varying differential size?

Comment: @Abhinav: Hi. I chose the simple example of a U-tube to illustrate that oscillation is inevitable and how roughly mathematically that works. But for geometrically more complex shapes (think e.g. a tanker part-loaded that stops abruptly!) it becomes exceedingly difficult to model. The only shape I can think of where a pseudo-exact derivation would work is a part-filled sphere or long cylinder (with long axis perpendicular to axis of motion).

Comment: Actually that's what I had in mind,I have had some prior knowledge as to what you explained and was looking for the wider application (in case it was possible,of course).

Comment: @Abhinav: It's never *impossible* of course, just really hard and increasingly less accurate (for irregular shapes). The model of a part-filled sphere with *jerk* could be very insightful for other, more complex geometries, for instance.

Comment: Level difference $y$ changes twice as fast as the liquid moves, so $v$ should be equal to $dy/2$. This changes $\omega$.

Comment: Why should a sphere be easier than a cuboid?

Comment: In agreement with @BoLe it was not the wisest idea to introduce $y$ as the height difference, it would be better to denote the distance from an equilibrium state therewith. If $U_0 = mgy_0/2$, it means that the potential energy is calculated with respect to that level, where the water level on the left side in beginning was. Without redefinition of the ground energy level, the system will never reach $U=0$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Gert is very insightful, but there is a slight error in the equation of motion. (Sorry, since I am new here, I cannot comment yet, therefore I have to write it as a separate answer.)

Instead of $y$ the variable should by $x$, which measures the height of the column from the equilibrium position (when the water levels are equal in both branches). It means, that the weight of the column, that exerts force is:

$2\rho A g x$

The equation of motion becomes:

$Ma+2\rho A g x=0$

The $a$ acceleration can be expressed as $a=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$, so

$M\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+2\rho A g x=0$

The important difference here is that when $x=0$, the force is indeed $0$, as it is expected. However, when in Gert's derivation $y=0$, the force is not $0$, because at that point there would be a column of height $y$ in the left branch of the tube, which would exert force on the system. $y=0$ is not an equilibrium position.

We can look for the solution in the form of $x=x_0\cos (\omega t)$, and the frequency will be:

$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{2\rho A g}{M}}$

If the length of the entire water 'column' in the tube is $L$, this can be simplified since $M=\rho A L$:

$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{2g}{L}}$

The problem you refer to in your question is known as 'sloshing' and it is a fairly complicated one. You can search for this term and find papers like this: 
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10665-010-9397-5

Also, you can find videos, which show that the surface behaves in a very complex way in the described situation. It wouldn't behave as a flat surface acting like a seesaw. The U-tube is a crude first assumption, but it gives some insights.

Comment: I'm sorry but this in incorrect *and should not have been voted as the correct answer*. It should be clear that if you take away the column of liquid of height $y$, no forces act on the rest of the fluid but while it's there the net force is indeed $\rho Ay$. The only situation where that is no longer true is when the fluid in the left column drops to *into the bend* but my diagram is clear on this. I do believe we have both overlooked something: the motion of the fluid in the bend is one of **rotation**, not translation. I believe this will affect the outcome and if so I will edit my answer.

Comment: So allow me a bit of time to explore the effect of *rotation vs. translation*.

Comment: I think there is a bit of misunderstanding. What I missed in your solution was that in the case of $y=0$ the force was 0. However, in this case the fluid would go up in the other branch and an unbalanced column of height y would be on the left exerting the same force. This issue is resolved in your new solution where the $y_1+y_2$ sum is a constant. 

However, there is one mistake: $du=2dy_1$ is true. But the velocity is the derivative of $y_1$: 

$a=\frac{d^2y_1}{dt^2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}$

Leading to: 

$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{4g}{2L-R\pi}}$

For $R=0$ it's the same as what I wrote.

Comment: Instead of calculating the forces directly it is actually better to use the energy balance as you started to do in your original solution. Then $\frac{d E}{dt}=0$ gives you directly the equations as it is illustrated here: 

http://web.mit.edu/8.01t/www/materials/InClass/WE_Sol_W13D1-2.pdf

Comment: About the rotation: the moment of inertia is $\int r^2 dm$. Since here r is a constant for all mass points, this would yield $mR^2$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}mR^2$.

This would cancel $R$ from the equation in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the point about $u$. But the IM of *half* a ring is half of $mR^2$. Point taken about the energy balance, thanks. Thanks for the *.pdf, something to remember!

Comment: I'm at a loss understanding the hydrostatic pressure along the tube and how the pressure difference drives the liquid. [See my (very similar) question.](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/266757/105590)

Comment: @Gert A half ring with mass $m$ and radius $R$ (the distance measured from the center of the complete ring) has a moment of inertia $mR^2$ with respect to the center of the (complete) ring.

Answer (score 3):

The answer I gave above is actually only approximately correct, if the radius of the circular bend is large compared to the radius of the U tube. The reason is that in the bent section the fluid actually *rotates* around its centre point, not *translates* as previously assumed. Look at the diagram below:

[image: U-tube with oscillating fluid.]

Firstly let's define a few things:

Total length of the fluid column, $L=y_1+\pi R + y_2$.

Total mass of the fluid, $M=\rho LA$.

Mass of the fluid contained in the bend, $m=\rho \pi RA$.

Force acting on the column, $F=\rho A(y_1-y_2)= \rho A(2y_1-L+\pi R)$.

This force now creates a *torque about the centre of the bend* that causes the *fluid in the bend* to experience *angular acceleration* $\alpha=\frac{d\omega}{dt}$, acc.:

$$\tau=FR=I \alpha,$$

where $I$ is the inertial moment of the fluid in the bend, $I=\frac{mR^2}{2}$, so:

$$FR=\frac{\rho \pi A R^3}{2}\alpha,$$

with $\alpha=\frac{d\omega}{dt}$ and $\frac{d\omega}{dt}=\frac{1}{R}\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{1}{R}a$, then:

$$F=\frac{\rho \pi A R}{2}a$$

However, $F$ is also responsible for the *translational acceleration of the fluid that is not contained in the bend*, which has a mass:

$$M-m$$

$$\rho A(L-\pi R)$$

Since as all the fluid experiences the same acceleration $a$, so we can write:

$$F=\frac{\rho \pi A R}{2}a+\rho A(L-\pi R)a$$

$$F=\rho A\frac{2L-\pi R}{2}a$$

With the expression for $F$ obtained higher up, we then get the equation of motion:

$$\rho A\frac{2L-\pi R}{2}a+\rho Ag(2y_1-L+\pi R)=0,$$

$$\frac{2L-\pi R}{2}a+(2y_1-L+\pi R)g=0$$

Now substitute: $u=2y_1-L+\pi R$, so:

$du=2dy_1$ and $a=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}$, so:

$$\frac{(2L-\pi R)}{4}\ddot{u}+gu=0,$$

which is the DE of the Harmonic Oscillator, with solution:

$$u=u_0\cos\omega t,$$

where:

$$\large{\omega=\sqrt{\frac{4g}{2L-\pi R}}}$$

Comment: The correct connection between $I$, $m$ and $R$ is $I=mR^2$ instead of $I=mR^2/2$, therefore $F=\rho A2L$. It doesn't matter if the tube is straight or curved below $y_1$, the only important property of that part (in our case) is the mass of the stored water therein. It doesn't matter if you calculate the inertial moment and torque, or the impulse and force, they must give the same. To become suspicious against your solution try to use your intuition and imagine the following scenario: you keep $L$ at constant, and change $R$. Would it change $\omega$?