# Period of small oscillations of liquid in a bottle

Tags: fluid-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator

I have seen that water in a bottle of water when perturbed invariably starts oscillation back and forth, with the shape of the water surface remaining intact.

I was wondering if there was any way to estimate the time period of these oscillations.

I think the problem can be modelled by considering an infinitely deep (my intuition says that depth doesn't play a role here) cylindrical well of given radius and neglecting viscous and surface tension effects.

The simplest method seemed to be to write the energy of the liquid at any moment and then differentiate after making the necessary approximations to hopefully obtain a differential equation for the simple harmonic oscillator.

Now the potential energy is simple enough to express in terms of the displacement variable, the kinetic energy is not. How do I decide how much of the fluid is set into motion and at what velocities? Since I'm looking for only an order of magnitude estimate, is there a valid approximation that I can make?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222179/fluid-filled-harmonic-oscillator/222211#222211. I would set up a general energy equation as you suggest, derive to time and then vary the amount of moving mass in the $K$ term.